# Fill in URL in a newly created reminder

Tags: applescript, automator

Since macOS Catalina, Reminders.app offers the possibility to fill in an URL in a reminder.

[image: URL in reminder]

> 2. Click the Info button, then add or change details.
>    <sub>*... Irrelevant part of the documentation ...*</sub>
>
>    - *Add a URL*: Click the URL field, and type a web address.

<sup>*Source: [https://support.apple.com/guide/reminders/add-a-reminder-from-another-app-on-mac-remn1f735fdc/mac#aria-apd1c83fe5ed6c04:~:text=Add%20a%20URL%3A%20Click%20the%20URL%20field%2C%20and%20type%20a%20web%20address.](https://support.apple.com/guide/reminders/add-a-reminder-from-another-app-on-mac-remn1f735fdc/mac#aria-apd1c83fe5ed6c04:%7E:text=Add%20a%20URL%3A%20Click%20the%20URL%20field%2C%20and%20type%20a%20web%20address.)*</sup>

I am trying, via Automator and with a bit of AppleScript, to create a reminder based upon a text in Chrome.
The goal would be, from a selected text in Chrome, to add a reminder with the URL of the page the selected text is coming from.

I am able to create the reminder properly, along with the name and the body, but I am struggling to fill in the URL field of a reminder.

I tried:

- ```
  set url of new_reminder to tab_url
  ```

  which errors with:

  > Reminders got an error: Can’t set URL of reminder id "x-apple-reminder://AB572176-9661-48FA-ADCF-795D0A912FED" to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask".
- ```
  set uri of new_reminder to tab_url
  ```

  which errors with:

  > Reminders got an error: Can’t make uri of reminder id "x-apple-reminder://2564FAFB-3825-442C-AAD5-BCA17E354D1B" into type specifier.

The first error makes me wonder if the URL should not be type casted into an URL object somehow?
But I am a bit lost on what I should be trying from here.

The macOS version I am on is ***10.15.5 (19F101)***.

---

Here is my current AppleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        set tab_name to get title of active tab of window 1
        set tab_url to get URL of active tab of window 1
        tell application "Reminders"
            set recipes to list "Recipes"
            tell recipes
                set new_reminder to make new reminder
                set name of new_reminder to tab_name
                set body of new_reminder to input
                (* set ??? of new_reminder to tab_url *)
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: RE: "Since macOS Catalina, Reminders.app offers the possibility to fill in an URL in a reminder." -- In a fresh clean install of **macOS Catalina** and with **Reminders** having one newly created _reminder_, then in **Script Editor** running `tell application "Reminders" to get properties of first reminder` and the _properties_ it returns does not contain an **URL** _property_. The **AppleScript** _Dictionary_ for **Reminders** shows: **reminder** _n_ [inh. item] : A reminder in the Reminders application -- an its _properties_ do not show anything related to that either.

Comment: Where are you getting your information from?

Comment: These are what shows for the _properties_ of a _reminder_: name, id, container, creation date, modification date, body, completed, completion date, due date, allday due date, remind me date, priority, flagged -- As you can see nothing **URL** related.

Comment: @user3439894 picture added in the question. So I guess that means that the reminder object does not allow this yet?

Comment: If I click the (i) _button_ it shows me only **remind me** and **priority**. How did you add the **URL**?

Comment: Odd, I did nothing special there. Here is my macOS version: 10.15.5 (19F101)

Comment: I have the same version of **macOS** as you, but my **Reminders** doesn't have what your picture has. What do you get if you query the _properties_ for that _reminder_ with **AppleScript**?

Comment: Sadly, the exact list you pointed at in your comment. I do see `name:Test reminder,` but the URL is nowhere to be found :/

Comment: Are you syncing your **Mac** with an **iPhone**? The reason I'm asking is because **Reminders** on **iOS 13** has an **URL** _field_, and this may be the reason you have it in a _reminder_ under **macOS Catalina**. But if it is a sync, that _property_ probably doesn't translate into an **AppleScript** _property_ (yet).

Comment: Yes this is indeed a shared list to someone using an iPhone on iOS 13.

Comment: As a workaround... I guess you could add the **URL** to the end of the _value_ of **body** _property_, e.g.: `set body of new_reminder to input & linefeed & linefeed & tab_url`

Comment: @user3439894 if you post the way to log/print the the properties as from your first comment, the list of said properties and so conclude that, as of today, this is not possible, I'd be happy to accept that as an answer, since, it is, for now, the only good answer there is. Also I find the piece of information giving the way to list properties that can be set really valuable of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, as of today ***28 November 2022***, the URL property is not accessible in the list of properties of a reminder that AppleScript can set — this was updated with the release of macOS Ventura, that didn't change the situation.

This is backed up by this piece of AppleScript, giving all the properties of a reminder:

```
tell application "Reminders"
    set reminder_properties to properties of first reminder
end tell
```

Given the reminder filled in as in the question,
[image: example reminder]

This piece of script yields the result:

```
{
  id:"x-apple-reminder://XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX", 
  creation date:date "Wednesday, 2 September 2020 at 19:49:45", 
  container:list id "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" of application "Reminders", 
  priority:0, 
  name:"Test reminder", 
  remind me date:missing value, 
  completed:false, 
  modification date:date "Wednesday, 2 September 2020 at 19:50:41", 
  due date:missing value, 
  completion date:missing value, 
  flagged:false, 
  body:missing value, 
  allday due date:missing value
}
```

Where we can definitely see that the URL filled in the reminder is nowhere to be seen.

---

This issue has been shared in Apple Feedback Assistant, with the feedback reference **FB9033612**.

---

<sub>*All credits for this answer goes to [@user3439894](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586975/fill-in-url-in-a-newly-created-reminder#comment112442761_63586975)*</sub>

---

For what it's worth, I ended up doing this with [Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/shortcuts-mac).